# Раскладывается или разлагается?

Tags: стилистика

Как правильно: "многочлен раскладывается на множители" или "многочлен разлагается на множители"?

Answer (score 1):

Глагол РАЗЛАГАТЬСЯ составляет видовую пару к глаголу РАЗЛОЖИТЬСЯ в трех значениях из четырех. Одним из них является 'разделиться на составные части, элементы (спец.)'.

Глагол РАСКЛАДЫВАТЬСЯ - "2. Страд. к *раскладывать*." Глагол РАСКЛАДЫВАТЬ в одном из значений также имеет 'разделить на составные части, элементы (спец.)'. *Разложить воду на кислород и водород*.

Если следовать логике МАСа, оба варианта возможны.

Comment: В обычном языке - да, хотя и в несколько разных ситуациях.
Но тут явно математический термин.С одной стороны, этот слэнг - вещь явно устоявшаяся и не всегла следующая логики самого ящыка. С другой - вряд ли где прописан явно на предмет нормы. Есть, конечно, математические словари, но они не носят орфоэпического характера.

Answer (score 0):

Это математический жаргон, вряд ли нормируется. 
Но вообще-то я чаще слышал "разлагается".